# Angular2: cannot run ng-xi18n. Metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, internationalization

I worked with the Angular 2 INTERNATIONALIZATION (I18N) to provide translation for an app. The cookbook recipe seemed straightforward, but while running ng-xi18n I get the following Error:

Error: Metadata version mismatch for module ...@angular/material/core/rtl/dir.d.ts, found version 3, expected 2

I am using

- angular 2.3.0
- node v6.9.5
- npm  v3.10.10

Is there a fix for this problem? If not are there any good alternatives for internationalization?